# Protecting Circuit - ESD

Tags: voltage, diodes, ethernet, esd, surge-protection

I'd like to know on how to select the transient protection circuit components for my Ethernet Interface.

I saw a reference design that uses a pair of [UCLAMP3301D](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/44000000MCod/Fs.eSBQs1U.304Nkc5rxRZ3Lk6_1A4.ZX_npjU1R.C8) and 2.2Ω series resistors to the jack to protect that PHY against rapid disconnect/connect transients as shown below.

[image]

I'd like to know the purpose of 2.2ohm resistor and how to select a different value if the diodes are different?

Can someone tell me whether the specifications of UCLAMP3301D are correct? If not, what should be the right set of specifications for this component for transient protection?
Just want to understand the logic so that I can search for cheaper alternative components (if any available)

The above image is for KSZ8863 device. I need to design a circuit for KSZ9131 device. Can you please help?

Comment: But you already said yourself what is the purpose of resistors so why do you ask what is the purpose of the resistors? Also the protection is differential mode only. Usually differential protection is used on the cable side, not on the PHY side. Isn't that a magjack which connects to PHY directly, no other transformers?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand your comment. Usually, in the reference designs that I saw, the MagJack is connected to the PHY via the Magnetics (Transformers)? I'm not able to understand what you mentioned about the resistors? Could you pleases explain what is the different mode protection?

Comment: To determine if the protection is adequate, you need to specify the transient. What standard do you need to comply with? We have no idea of the end use of your design - it could be automotive, industrial or for a home router. Different standards with different requirements.

Comment: Its for Ethernet industrial

Comment: Your schematics show AN2157 as reference. It tells you about the protection circuit, diodes and resistor calculation. Does the appnote answer your question?

Comment: Please link to the reference design @Newbie

Comment: The difference is that with 1GE, will the parasitic capacitance offered by the ESD diodes will affect the signal quality and cause distortion on the differential signal lines?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know the purpose of 2.2ohm resistor and how to select a
> different value if the diodes are different?

The 2.2Ω resistors are most likely there to provide a small amount of resistance so if there is a high voltage spike it would take the path of lowest impedance through the diodes instead of heading to the transformer. A fast transient would much rather travel through the capacitance of the diode instead of going through the 2.2Ω resistor, not to mention that the common mode filter would provide additional impedance, but you want to stop some of the brunt of the transient and slow it down. A good thing to do would be to check the eye diagram with a diff probe and see if the resistors change it vs different values (such as 0 ohms). You could also test the final design with TVS and without and see how it changes the eye diagram.

You may want to check these out if designing for the KSZ9131, they contain most of the info you'd need to finish a design:
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/KSZ9131MNX-Hardware-Design-Checklist-00003371A.pdf

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/00002157B.pdf

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/00002054A.pdf

Also, a good idea would be to use the reference design as much as possible from the eval board, in that way you can ensure that the design has been tested and works (as long as you implement it properly). You could also buy a dev kit and experiment a bit with different options sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please tell me the spec of the TVS diode that I need to select? What should be the clamping voltage?